gradle-docker-compose - Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'ComposeExtension'
Recently a project of mine has started failing unprompted. When I would run gradle test (launching the project remotely using Jenkins) the project would instead return the following error:
* Where:

Build file '/tmp/jenkins-eef6ce11/workspace/my_project/build.gradle' line: 6



* What went wrong:

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose', version: '0.17.7']

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.avast.gradle.docker-compose']

   > Cannot create a proxy class for abstract class 'ComposeExtension'.

Since I hadn't made any changes at all before this error started appearing, I suspected it might be an issue with outdated plugins or dependencies, but updating them to the newest versions did not help. Here is my build.gradle file for reference:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.avast.gradle.docker-compose" version "0.17.7"
}
apply plugin: 'docker-compose'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.23.0'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:4.23.0'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.23.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.5'
    testImplementation('io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.5'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.18.1'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:7.18.1'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20240303'
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

ext {
    testJvmArguments = []
    if (project.hasProperty('grid')) {
        testJvmArguments << "-Dgrid=true"
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('zap')) {
        testJvmArguments << '-Dzap=true'
    }
}

allprojects {
    compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        systemProperties(System.getProperties())
        testLogging {
            events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
        }
        testJvmArguments.each {
            j -> jvmArgs(j)
        }
    }

}

test {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suites 'src/test/resources/testng.xml'
    }
}

I'm not sure what could have caused this problem in the first place and as such don't know what steps to take to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.
